# Return Image URL from Paperclip using RABL

Tags: mongoid, paperclip, rabl

I have a user model with Paperclip for avatars and I need to be able to return the `image_url` for each size (small, medium, large) using RABL.

In mongoid model i would simply do  `self.avatar(:original)` but now nothing works, I just get an empty response in the attachment

```
"user" : {
  "id" : "50b204e10eae9c55fa000028",
  "paperclip::attachment" : {},
  "name" : "My Name"
}
```

**/models/user.rb**

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :original => ['1000x1000>', :jpg],
      :small    => ['64x64#',           :jpg],
      :medium   => ['250x250',    :jpg],
      :large    => ['500x500>',   :jpg]
    }
```

**/views/posts/base.json.rabl**

```
child :user do
    attributes :id, :name

    child :avatar do
        attributes :original
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
child :user do
  attributes :id, :name

  node :avatar_original do |u|
    u.avatar(:original)
  end
end
```